# Do You Have a Flag?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, flags

[image: Do You Have a Flag?]

Clues: [contextual images] 
0056(9:30)8
(6:15)(6:15)(6:00)800

Instructions: Name That Country

_ _ _ A _ _ _

Comment: Re your suggested edit to my answer, which Wikipedia page is your source for this? The one I linked to shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRtdu.png). (Happy to change my answer to match another source - I just couldn't find an exact match myself... Thanks.)

Comment: I searched Ukraine on Wikipedia, then used an online color picker to find the colors from the flag image on the wiki page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The country is:

> **UKR[A]INE**

The mention of a 'flag' in the title is doing double duty:

> 1. First, the times in brackets need to be interpreted in terms of *hands on a clock* and then converted via the flag-related code, **[semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore)**. This way, 9:30 translates as 'B', 6:15 as 'F', and 6:00 as 'D'.
>
>  2. Then, with a little bit of tinkering - specifically, raising the digit immediately before a time by 1 (e.g. 6 up to 7) and lowering the digit immediately after a time by 1 (e.g. 8 down to 7) - you can produce strings of 6 characters that represent **hex codes for colours**. Specifically, #0057B7 (azure) and #FFD700 (gold). When the two rectangles are coloured accordingly, you produce a **country flag** - and that flag is [the flag of **UKRAINE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Ukraine).
>
>  [image: Flag of Ukraine]

Comment: rot13 Envfvat ybjrevat orsber nsgre - Is it a usual transform, used by many puzzles? Or a unique one, more like “guess what random transform I made”? Asking just for learning.

Comment: @Pumbaa Actually it potentially appears to be a case of differing sources! The [information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRtdu.png) on the Wiki page I linked to in my answer would require a kind of 'guess this transformation' strategy, but I was pretty confident by that point of what the answer was, and I kinda 'backfilled' the transformation in order to 'make it fit'. However, the OP made a comment in a suggested edit implying that they have another source which suggests the 6, 8 and other 8 should be left alone without any need for transformation at all. I don't yet know its origin though.